# Running other java versions on OSX

Tags: java, macos

Sorry if this seems like it's for SuperUser. I just deleted it there :)

I am running this command on OSX

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5/Home/bin/java -version
```

and the response is

`java version "1.6.0_17`"

Is there any way to really run an older version of Java without downloading to a makeshift location?

OSX 10.6.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only Java 6 is available on Snow Leopard. The JavaVM framework has links for 1.4 and 1.5, but both of those links point to "CurrentJDK", which in turn points to 1.6, so even if you invoke the `java` executables in the 1.5 directory, you still get the 1.6 (Java 6) executable.

If you really need (32-bit) Java 5, you can get it by following [these instructions](http://wiki.oneswarm.org/index.php/OS_X_10.6_Snow_Leopard).

Answer (score 1):

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions
```

can contain multiple versions. The symlink `Current` will point to the preferred, but you can choose which one to run just by specifying the path (as you've done above)

Comment: I think a clean install of SnowLeopard only gives you 1.6, though.

Comment: But that doesn't preclude your downloading another version.  Brian's answer is to the point and addressing the question regarding "makeshift location".

Comment: Hi Brian, no you cannot, as the question states. You can also NOT download other versions for 10.6, or at least not from Apple/Sun.

Mine is an upgrade 10.6 and it still only gives you Java 1.6

Comment: @yar - that's not what you asked. mipadi's answer demonstrates how to get different JDKs/JREs. I'm currently looking at versions 1.3/4/5/6 JDKs on my Snow Leopard machine

Comment: @Brian, perhaps you're right, my point was that running the JVMs in versions does NOT actually give you different vesions by default. Thank you for your answer.